# Caesar Cipher code in Python: convert to unicode + shift value then return back as encrypted message

Tags: python, encryption, unicode, alphabet

I need to ask the user for 2 inputs:

1. enter a message
2. enter a shift value

Then take their message and convert it to unicode using the ord() function.
Then add their shift value to come up with a new unicode value.
And then convert that new value back to an encrypted message using the chr() function.

I'm struggling to even get started on this and the ord() function only takes one letter at a time, so I don't know how to use that function on a whole sentence from the user.

Please help as this is what I have so far. Thank you so much!

```
text = (input('Type message: '))
shift_value = (input('Type shift value: '))


def ceasar(text, shift_value):
    for i in text():
        print(ord(i))
        return
```

Comment: `return ''.join(chr(ord(ch) + shift_value) for ch in text)`

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an an answer if you think it's right.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = 0x10FFFF
def ceasar_encrypt(text, k):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(ch) + k) % N) for ch in text)

def ceasar_decrypt(ciphertext, k):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(ch) - k) % N) for ch in ciphertext)


text = input('Type a message: ')
k = int(input('Type shift value: '))

ciphertext = ceasar_encrypt(text, k)
print(ciphertext)
plaintext = ceasar_decrypt(ciphertext, k)
print(plaintext)
```